# Won't turn on after dead battery

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I have mountain lion on MacBook pro mid 2012.

So if my battery dies, because I left noSleep on or just because of being sat untouched for a week off of 2%, when I turn my computer on, Instead of the picture of the screen last used with the loading bar under it, the apple logo with the loading bar. I let it sit for a while, and it stays at the last bar of the loading thing. I wait and wait and nothing. I have to reboot using the power button to get it to work. A message then appears that said "your computer shut down cuz of a problem" . I have always saved my work
, but I am assuming it would all be deleted if I had an unsaved word doc on low battery.

What is going on?

Things I have tried:
 reset SMC
Reinstall OS on network recovery

And eventually if I have to, I guesss I will have to factory reset it

Comment: Take the battery out and try without it.

Comment: What does `About This Mac > More Info > System Report > Power > Battery Informaion` report?

Comment: Model Information:
  Serial Number: W023949UZD3LC
  Manufacturer: SMP
  Device Name: bq20z451
  Pack Lot Code: 0
  PCB Lot Code: 0
  Firmware Version: 201
  Hardware Revision: 000a
  Cell Revision: 165
  Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh): 3793
  Fully Charged: No
  Charging: No
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 5127
  Health Information:
  Cycle Count: 141
  Condition: Normal
  Battery Installed: Yes
  Amperage (mA): -30
  Voltage (mV): 11860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this sounds like a missing or corrupt sleep image.

When your Mac loses power thanks to the battery draining it *should* enter [Safe Sleep](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1757).  Safe sleep relies on a functioning sleep image to store the contents of memory once power is lost.  This sleep image is located at **/private/var/vm/sleepimage**.

I'm not familiar enough with noSleep to know if it removes/prevents this image but it wouldn't surprise me if this was the case since it's main function is to prevent the Mac from sleeping.

---

My first plan of action would be to remove the current sleep image using this command in terminal, you will be prompted to enter your admin password once you enter the command:

```
sudo rm /private/var/vm/sleepimage
```

Following that command I would restart the Mac using  > Restart...

Once the Mac restarts I would use the following command in terminal to check the size of the sleep image, it will likely be the same size as the amount of installed RAM in the Mac:

```
ls -lh /private/var/vm/sleepimage
```

---

If for whatever reason either command returns an error then your sleep image likely doesn't exist, which would explain the problem.  If this is the case then I would either uninstall noSleep or contact someone involved with the development (I believe it's open source) to ask about a change in it's behavior or a possible fix.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Yep! I already reinstalled everything for a different reason, and it got fixed, no hardware

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a defective hardware issue. Take your Mac to an authorized Apple repair/service center, or an Apple Store, and have them diagnose the problem. If it is under warranty, or if you purchased AppleCare to extend the warranty, they will replace any faulty components.